# Pass value of the variable to a command in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I pass the value of the variable to a command in a bash script?

Specifically, I want to create a AWS S3 bucket with (partially) random name. This is what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
random_id=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)
bucket_name=s3://mybucket-$random_id
echo Bucket name: ${bucket_name}
aws s3 mb ${bucket_name}
```

The output I get:

```
Bucket name: s3://mybucket-z4nnli2k
 Parameter validation failed:cket-z4nnli2k
": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"
```

The bucket name is generated correctly, but `aws s3 mb ${bucket_name}` fails. If I just run `aws s3 mb s3://mybucket-z4nnli2k` then the bucket is created, so I assume that `aws s3 mb ${bucket_name}` is not the correct way to pass the value of the `bucket_name` to the `aws s3 mb` command.

It must be something obvious but I have almost zero experience with shell scripts and can't figure it out.

How do I pass the value of `bucket_name` to the `aws s3 mb` command?

Comment: Are you sure the bucket name is correct?  Yours contains a `:` and the regex it says it has to match doesn't include colons or forward slashes.  Other than, you should pretty much always quote your variables

Comment: This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/680) could be useful

Comment: You have extra CRs, LFs, and a space in the bucket name.

Comment: @EricRenouf `aws s3 mb s3://mybucket-z4nnli2k` absolutely works. So the generated bucket name must be correct. Not sure you mean by "quote your variables"? Should it be `aws s3 mb "${bucket_name}"` or something else?

Comment: @lexicore that is how it should be to prevent word splitting and globbing, so it's good practice.  Given what Ignacio says that probably won't solve the problem though, perhaps you need to `dos2unix` the script

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That was it, thank you.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Just out of curiosity, how did you find that CRLF endings were the issue?

Comment: I noticed inconsistencies in the output.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I honestly think you should post this as the answer with a detailed explanation. Not sure what was the inconsistency you were referring to

Comment: @Inian Absolutely agree.

Comment: I don't know aws, but the error message states that a bucket name is not allowed to contain a colon nor a forward slash, but your bucket name contains both.

Comment: @user1934428 Since `aws s3 mb s3://mybucket-z4nnli2k` works, the regex does not apply to the `s3://` prefix.

Comment: In this case, I would run the script with `-x` to see what is really passed to aws. Since aws complains about  an illegal character, there must be one somewhere....

Comment: @user1934428 As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams found out, I had bad line returns in my script. `dos2unix` fixed it. Thanks for the `-x` tip!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above, this is what I got working:

```
#!/bin/bash
random_id=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)
bucket_name=s3://mybucket-$random_id
echo Bucket name: ${bucket_name}
aws s3 mb "${bucket_name}"
```

I also had to run `dos2unix` on the script, apparently there were bad line breaks.

Comment: The way you write your `echo`, you can't see whether bucket_name has a trailing space. Write it as `echo "Bucket name: '$bucket_name'"`